# Replace a part of the current URL

Tags: javascript

I want to add a modified link on a 404 page because I moved the permalink structure from domain.tld/category/title to domain.tld/title.
Now when a visitor found an old link to domain.tld/category/title she/he will see the 404 page and there should be a dynamic link to domain.tld/title.
This link should be generated if window.location.href contains five "/" (because of http://www.domain.tld/category/title/ has five "/" and my new permalink structure won't have five "/" but only four "/".
I know I can replace (remove) the category part with this code:

```
function geturl(){
 var url = window.location.href;
 alert(url.replace('/category/', '/'));
}
```

The problem with that is that I have to define a static category name but it could be anything.
How to get rid of /category/ part dynamically when there are five "/" in window.location.href?

Comment: Sounds like something that should be redirected by the web server..

Comment: Ugly solution: url.replace(/\/\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\//,"//$1/$3");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function geturl(url){
    if (typeof url === 'string'){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        url = a.pathname;
    }
    else url = window.location.pathname;
    alert(url.replace(/^\/[^\/]+\//, '/'));
}
```

Call this function using `geturl('your url')`. If no url is passed, it'll use the page's current url. The regular expression will replace a string at the beginning of the URL's path portion which is inside 2 `/` characters.

Comment: ... *Where is* the explanation? (sorry, assumed "donde esta" was Spanglishy enough to be understood. ;) My bad!)

Comment: Wasn't me, but it may be because you have a `^` at the start (which won't match any `window.location.href`.

Comment: Took back my downvote because this now works, but I still don't think it fully answers the question because there is no conditional for how many segments the url contains.

Comment: I just realized the OP meant 4 and 5 as the count of slashes total in the URL

Answer (score 0):

*Preface: this really should be handled by the web server (not your web page), as [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392044/mike-christensen) mentioned.*

---

**[RegExPal](http://regexpal.com/) seems to agree with this:**

```
var url = "http://www.domain.tld/category/title/";

url.replace(/\/[^/.]+?\//, "");
```

*Note: not including a "g" in the RegExp will only allow the first instance to be replaced.*

---

**That being said, you don't need RegEx. You could just `split` and then `join` the URL:**

```
var parts = x.split("/");
parts.splice(3,1);
window.location.href = parts.join("/");
```

Comment: Thanks, @DJDavid98! Copy-pasted incorrectly. :) Updated.

Answer (score 0):

it will remove category from url

```
 function geturl(){
     var url = window.location.pathname; // get url from browser
    // var url = 'http://www.domain.tld/category/title/'; // get url from browser
     var url_array = url.split('/category/');
     var newurl = url_array[0]+"/"+url_array[1];
     alert(newurl);
    }
```